# Как передать через метод POST сущности со связью Many-to-Many?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mvc

Проектирую MVC - приложение и возникли затруднения с добавлением данных в БД.
Имею базу данных с 3 сущностями, между которыми связь Many-to-Many:

```
public class Employee
{
[Required] public long Id { get; set; }

[Required] public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

public ICollection<EmployeeSkill>? Skill { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
[Required] public long Id { get; set; }
[Required] public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<EmployeeSkill>? Employees { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeSkill
{
[Required] public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
[Required,ForeignKey("EmployeeId")] public Employee Employee{ get; set; }


[Required] public long SkillId { get; set; }
[Required,ForeignKey("SkillId")] public Skill Skill{ get; set; }

[Required] public byte Level { get; set; }
}
```

Данные сущности необходимо передать в контроллер, в методе POST и создать далее соответствующие строки таблицы.
Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF. Также не помешают версии .NET и ASP.NET. Иначе вам могут дать ответ, который вам не подойдёт.

Comment: EF - 6.0.8
.NET - 6.0
ASP - 6.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Для создания этих сущностей вам нужно имя работника, название умения и уровень.
Создадим модель для них:

```
public class EmployeeSkillModel
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
}
```

Метод контроллера должен иметь параметр этого типа. Что-то вроде:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeSkillModel employeeSkillModel)
```

Далее делаем валидацию (оставляю это вам) и создаём наши сущности:

```
var employee = new Employee { Name = employeeSkillModel.EmployeeName };
var skill = new Skill { Name = employeeSkillModel.SkillName };
var employeeSkill = new EmployeeSkill { Employee = employee, Skill = skill, Level = employeeSkillModel.Level };

db.EmployeeSkills.Add(employeeSkill);

db.SaveChanges();
```

---

---

Теперь немного выскажу свои мысли.

В ваших моделях `Employee` и `Skill` определены свойства-коллекции `EmployeeSkill` - это так называемые join entity (сущность соединения). Я бы порекомендовал сделать прямые навигационные свойства:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Required] public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Skill>? Skills { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill>? EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    [Required] public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee>? Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill>? EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
}
```

При этом join entity можно оставить, т. к. она у вас имеет payload (нагрузку) в виде свойства `Level` и к ней нужно иметь доступ.
Обратите внимание, что имена коллекций во множественном числе.

---

Вероятно, навыки в БД не должны повторяться. Для этого на свойство `Name` сущности `Skill` следует навесить ограничение уникальности: `[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]`. То есть если в БД уже имеется Skill с каким-то названием, то не создавать новый, а использовать имеющийся.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть еще один вопрос. Мы получается с контроллера должны получить сущность EmployeeSkillModel, которая будет включать все основные атрибуты Employee и должна содержать список со Skill.  В цикле foreach нужно перебрать все скиллы и создать соответствующие записи?

Comment: По заданию я должен передать с Employee именно список Skills